# Why do all Spring Roo testRemove() tests fail after creating an ApplicationContext object?

Tags: spring, junit, applicationcontext

In my first **Spring Roo** project, I noticed a strange behaviour while testing the auto-generated entity tests (entity jpa --class ~.xyz --testAutomatically):

In every generated **xyzIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj** file, the **testRemove()** test, such as

```java
@Test
public void xyzImplIntegrationTest.testRemove() {
    xyzImpl obj = dod.getRandomxyzImpl();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Data on demand for 'xyzImpl' failed to initialize correctly", obj);
    Long id = obj.getId();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Data on demand for 'xyzImpl' failed to provide an identifier", id);
    obj = xyzImpl.findxyzImpl(id);
    obj.remove();
    obj.flush();
    // this is the assertion that does not hold
    Assert.assertNull("Failed to remove 'xyzImpl' with identifier '" + id + "'", xyzImpl.findxyzImpl(id));
}
```

, fail in the JUnit test queue **after** I add the following artificial test and test it before the others.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class DummyTest {

  @Test
  public void ArtificialTest() 
  {
    ApplicationContext ac = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
      // the same problem occurs for
      // new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");

    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Note that all tests run without errors if executed independently and that I have not modified the applicationContext.xml provided by Spring Roo at all.

---

My questions are now:

- **Is this a known bug with an existing workaround or am I missing something important?**
- **Is there another way to get the application context for an individual written test?**

---

Below you find the corresponding failure trace:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to remove 'xyzImpl' with identifier '1' 
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93) 
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43) 
at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:551) 
at xyzImplIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.ajc$interMethod$xyzImplIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest$xyzImplIntegrationTest$testRemove(xyzImplIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:118) 
at xyzImplIntegrationTest.testRemove(xyzImplIntegrationTest.java:1) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45) 
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) 
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42) 
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) 
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) 
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) 
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```